# How to play video by entering URL through input field using javascript

Tags: javascript, video

I am trying to make a page so that I can enter a URL through the input field and on submitting it will play the video. But unfortunately it's not happening like that.
I am working with a local file on my PC.

**JavaScript**

```js
window.onload=function(){
     alert('Your video player is Here');
}
function play(){
    var path  = document.getElementById("path").value;
    document.getElementById('show').innerHTML='<video id="movie" src="'+url+'" height="600px" width="1300px" controls autoplay > </video>';
    var player =document.getElementById('movie');
    player.load();
    alert(''+player.duration);
}
```

**HTML**

```html
<input type="text" id="path" placeholder="put movie path"/>
    <input type="submit" onclick="play();" value="Play on"/>
    <div id="show"></div>
```

Comment: Try the HTML5 video tag

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You declare a variable called `path` to store value from the input field, but then you try to use a variable called `url` when changing the video source.

Answer (score 0):

url variable is not declared. You can rename the path variable to url in order to make it work. Use the code below

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.onload=function(){
         alert('Your video player is Here');
    }
        function play(){
        var url = document.getElementById("path").value;
        document.getElementById('show').innerHTML='<video  id="movie" src="'+url+'" height="600px" width="1300px" controls autoplay > </video>';
        var player =document.getElementById('movie');
        player.load();
        alert(''+player.duration);

        }
    </script>
```

JSFIDDLE:http://jsfiddle.net/1sug6ucr/

Hope this helps you